# How can I make columns of images/links collapse responsively for an email template

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

Ive been given a task to make the links (which are also images) go from 6 horizontal links, then collapsing them into 3 and then 3 on top of each other.

The catch here is its for en email template to be sent out. And although I have been making my template responsive, it only seems to go from 6 links in a horizontal line, to 6 links aligned vertically. No mini collapsing in between? Just straight horizontal, or straight vertical.

My main dilemma, is because this is for email, I am forced to do everything with inline CSS, something im not to keen on..

Ive tried using flex (obviously wont work) tried using different implementations of tables, but I cant get it to collapse in the desired manner...

Goal: To get it from going 6 horizontal, to collapsing to 3 and 3 on top of each other vertically. Any advice or help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

NOTE I only put 2 as there was no need to do it up to 6, but this is the usual approach I was taking

```
<center>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="templateColumns">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" width="50%" class="templateColumnContainer">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="leftColumnContent">
                                <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/480/300" width="280" style="max-width:280px;" class="columnImage" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    </table>
                </td>
                <td align="center" valign="top" width="50%" class="templateColumnContainer">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="rightColumnContent">
                                <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/480/300" width="280" style="max-width:280px;" class="columnImage" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </center>

<style type="text/css">
        @media only screen and (max-width: 640px){
            .templateColumnContainer{
                display:block !important;
                width:100% !important;
            }
        }
    </style>
```

Comment: Supply example code, what you;ve tried, etc..

Comment: Sorry for some reason I wasnt done typing this out and it submitted the post before I was even done? I edited it and added what was suppose to be there originally. Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THis is what got the closest success as flex WILL NOT work with email services, although it wasn't inline, the only aspect that wont work in terms of responsive email is:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
                   .non-flex-inner-container {
                       display: inline-block;
                   }
          }
```

as this cannot be made inline to my knowledge..
Here is the closest success:

```
<style type="text/css">
        .non-flex-container {
            display: inline;
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
            float: left;
          }

          .non-flex-inner-container {
            display: inline;
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
          }

          .non-flex-element {
            display: inline;
          }

          @media (max-width: 600px) {
                   .non-flex-inner-container {
                       display: inline-block;
                   }
          }

    </style>

<div class="non-flex-container">
        <div class="non-flex-inner-container">
            <div class="non-flex-element">
                <a href="#"><img src="img" alt="" width="100" height="10" style="margin:10px;"/></a>
            </div>
            <div class="non-flex-element">
                <a href="#"><img src="img" alt="" width="50" height="10" style="margin:10px;"/></a>
            </div>
            <div class="non-flex-element">
                <a href="#"><img src="img" alt="" width="70" height="10" style="margin:10px;"/></a>
            </div>
        </div><br>

        <div class="non-flex-inner-container">
            <div class="non-flex-element">
                <a href="#"><img src="img" alt= width="40" height="10" style="margin:10px;"/></a>
            </div>
            <div class="non-flex-element">
                <a href="#"><img src="img" alt="" width="40" height="10" style="margin:10px;"/></a>
            </div>
            <div class="non-flex-element">
                <a href="#"><img src="img" alt="" width="100" height="10" style="margin:10px;"/></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

---

This was complete success in terms of email and inline css, HOWEVER I was only able to achieve this with AMP pages, and apparently email services arent able to freely send amp pages unless said person whitelists you... Which completely defeats the purpose regardless...

---

```
width:100%; float:left;">  
        <div class="non-flex-inner-container" style="display:inline; text-align:center; width:100%;">
            <div class="non-flex-element" style="display:inline;">
                <a href=""><amp-img src="img" alt="" width="100" height="10" style="margin:10px;" media="(min-width: 600px)" /></amp-img></a>
            </div>
            <div class="non-flex-element" style="display:inline;">
                <a href=""><amp-img src="img" alt="" width="50" height="10" style="margin:10px;" media="(min-width: 600px)"/></amp-img></a>
            </div>
            <div class="non-flex-element" style="display:inline;">
                <a href=""><amp-img src="img" alt="" width="70" height="10" style="margin:10px;" media="(min-width: 600px)"/></amp-img></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="non-flex-inner-container" style="display:inline; text-align:center; width:100%;">
            <div class="non-flex-element" style="display:inline;">
                <a href=""><amp-img src="img" alt="" width="40" height="10" style="margin:10px;" media="(min-width: 600px)"/></amp-img></a>
            </div>
            <div class="non-flex-element" style="display:inline;">
                <a href=""><amp-img src="img" alt="" width="40" height="10" style="margin:10px;" media="(min-width: 600px)"/></amp-img></a>
            </div>
            <div class="non-flex-element" style="display:inline;">
                <a href=""><amp-img src="img" alt="" width="100" height="10" style="margin:10px;" media="(min-width: 600px)"/></amp-img></a>
            </div>
        </div>



        <!-- Display Inline-block when less than 600px -->
        <div class="non-flex-container" style="display:inline; text-align:center; width:100%; float:left;">  
            <div class="non-flex-inner-container" style="display:inline-block;" text-align:center; width:100%;">
                <div class="non-flex-element" style="display:inline;">
                    <a href=""><amp-img src="img" alt="" width="100" height="10" style="margin:10px;" media="(max-width: 600px)" /></amp-img></a>
                </div>
                <div class="non-flex-element" style="display:inline;">
                    <a href=""><amp-img src="img" alt="" width="50" height="10" style="margin:10px;" media="(max-width: 600px)"/></amp-img></a>
                </div>
                <div class="non-flex-element" style="display:inline;">
                    <a href=""><amp-img src="img" alt="" width="70" height="10" style="margin:10px;" media="(max-width: 600px)"/></amp-img></a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="non-flex-inner-container" style="display:inline-block;" text-align:center; width:100%;">
                <div class="non-flex-element" style="display:inline;">
                    <a href=""><amp-img src="img" alt="" width="40" height="10" style="margin:10px;" media="(max-width: 600px)"/></amp-img></a>
                </div>
                <div class="non-flex-element" style="display:inline;">
                    <a href=""><amp-img src="img" alt="" width="40" height="10" style="margin:10px;" media="(max-width: 600px)"/></amp-img></a>
                </div>
                <div class="non-flex-element" style="display:inline;">
                    <a href=""><amp-img src="img" alt="" width="100" height="10" style="margin:10px;" media="(max-width: 600px)"/></amp-img></a>
                </div>
            </div>


    </div>
```

The conclusion... It isnt possible yet.... If anyone else has any more insight, please let me know. Big thanks to @Rustam Goygov for the insight and guidance!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the resolution to your problem using flex and having divs. I don't see the need of nested tables. 
[Js Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/GoygovRustam/jux9qg4e/3/)

Html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner-container">
        <div class="element">
            <img src="whatever" alt="Fragrances"/>
        </div>
        <div class="element">
            <img src="whatever" alt="Wicks"/>
        </div>
        <div class="element">
            <img src="whatever" alt="Vessels"/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="inner-container">
        <div class="element">
            <img src="whatever" alt="Wax"/>
        </div>
        <div class="element">
            <img src="whatever" alt="Kits"/>
        </div>
        <div class="element">
            <img src="whatever" alt="Diffusers"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And Styles:

```
.element {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px black solid;
}

.inner-container {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
        .container {
            display: block;
        }
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
        .container {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank Rustam! This is pretty much what im trying to do but without flex.

Answer (score 0):

Try float left and width 100% ...

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but it still has the same behavior of snapping into straight 6 vertical aligned images rather than slowly collapsing into smaller columns.